# Is there any way to get the recording url and timeline of Microsoft Teams meeting using GRAPH API's

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to fetch the recording details and timeline file using GRAPH API of Teams, but it is not there is there any way we can fetch them?

I can able to fetch the recording using one drive but issue is we need to grant drive scopes which is not good, can't we achieve using teams graph API's? also timeline of the meeting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Teams meeting Record** link is available in Graph Beta API under Chat messages - callRecordingUrl.

[chatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0), [eventMessageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/eventmessagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0), [callRecordingEventMessageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecordingeventmessagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)

1. Please go through [List chats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-4-list-all-chats-that-have-a-member-with-a-specific-display-name) documentation to get chat ID. Alternatively You can get the chat id directly if you create a meeting using Graph API. You can directly take chat id from here and perform next step [image]
2. Run this example in [List messages in a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request) by replacing the chat ID with your chat ID. In the response you will see eventDetail object with callRecordingUrl. Attaching a screenshot for your reference.
   [image]

Please follow these docs for **Timelines**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks for detailed message, but we cannot access that recording url without having files/site scopes or session. I'm looking for different approach as I need to do this on as an background job and I would have user access_token for that.

Regarding timeline above mentioned links are for attendance report. What I'm looking for is the timeline having speaker's speak start time and end time for all speakers.

Comment: 1. Engineering team has confirmed that it is currently not supported.
2. Currently there is no API to get start/end time for all speakers.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for details. I did't found the solution but I'm accepting your answer.